# Issue while deploying react app through netlify - environment variables

Tags: reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, netlify

Added the API key in .env file and used REACT_APP_ prefixed in that file.
locally the setup was working and data's was fetched from API.

**Issue is:**

While trying to deploy react app (CRA) through Netlify, i added the environment variables (Name - REACT_APP_API_KEY and Value as xxxxxxx..). But on saving those changes, the application is not fetching the data from API.

Anybody knows issue?

Comment: Did you rebuild the application after adding the environment variables?

Comment: thanks man!!! i thought it would automatically build, issue got resolved